# How to place a custom button right next to the alert title in Vuetify 3?

Tags: vuetify.js

Here is my alert code in Vuetify 3-

```
<v-alert type="warning" title="Title goes here">
  <div class="d-flex align-center justify-end">
    <v-btn variant="tonal">Custom action</v-btn>
  </div>
</v-alert>
```

Above code produces the following result-

[image]

I want the custom button to be at the same height as the alert title as displayed in the image below-

[image]

I wasn't able to find an "append" slot or something similar to fix this issue.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
<v-alert type="warning">       
  <div class="d-flex align-center justify-space-between">
    <div>Title Goes here</div>
    <v-btn variant="tonal">Custom action</v-btn>
  </div>
</v-alert>
```

**EDIT--**

If you want the icon at left also be aligned with the title then removing the default icon and setting it manually can also help.

```
<v-alert type="warning" :icon="false">       
  <div class="d-flex align-center justify-space-between"> 
    <div>
      <v-icon class="me-4">mdi-help-circle</v-icon>
      Title Goes here
    </div>
    <v-btn variant="tonal">Custom action</v-btn>
  </div>
</v-alert>
```

Comment: this almost works. The problem is that the icon is not centered vertically anymore.